# In the set $Z_n=\left\{0, 1, 2, ..., n-1\right\}$ for $n\geq 1$ why is it $n -1$ for the last term, also why are $1$ and $-1 = n -1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the set $Z_n$ = {$0, 1, 2, ..., n-1$}  for  $n$ $\geq$ $1$ why is it $n -1$ for the last term, also why are $1$ and $-1$ = $n -1$?

The full example question is as follows: In the set $Z_n$ = {0, 1, 2, ..., n-1}  for  n $\geq$ 1 is a cyclic group under addition modulo n. $1$ and $-1$ = $n - 1$ are generators.

Similarly, in the statement: If a has finite order say, n, then  = { e, a, $a^2$, ..., $a^{n-1}$} and $a^i$ = $a^j$ if and only if n divides i - j. Why is it n -1 for the last power.

Possibly because we need to subtract e from the set?

Comment: That sentence should be parsed as $(1$ and $(-1 = n-1))$ are generators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really we have $\mathbb{Z}_n = \{[0], [1],[2],\dots,[n-1]\}$ where for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ we let $[k]$ denote the class of $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$. These classes are defined so that $[k_1] = [k_2]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ if and only if $n$ divides $k_1 - k_2$. This is why $[-1] = [n-1]$ since $(n-1) - (-1) = n$ and $n$ divides $n$. Often people will just write $\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ for convenience and it is understood they actually represent classes. Also another notation that is sometimes used is $\bar{k}$ for the class of $k$ modulo $n$.

Thus we can write any of the following

$$\mathbb{Z}_4 = \{[0],[1],[2],[3]\}$$
$$\mathbb{Z}_4 = \{[1],[2],[3],[4]\}$$
$$\mathbb{Z}_4 = \{[-1],[0],[2],[3]\}$$

or infinitely many other choices of representatives of our classes. The first is the most common way, but the others are correct too. Observe this works since $[0] = [4]$ and $[-1] = [3]$ in our example. So, in each of the examples above all 4 classes are present. Note there are exactly 4 classes in $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and will be exactly $n$ classes in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Comment: Im a lot less lost now but still confused about certain things. Why is [0] = [4] and [-1] = [3]? Every class is equal to every other class in $Z_4$? Why did you choose (n - 1) to be $k_1$ and -1 to be $k_2$?

Comment: Recall $[k_1] = [k_2]$ if and only if $n$ divides $k_1 - k_2$. With this we check that $4 - 0 = 4$ and $3 - (-1) = 4$ both of which are divisible by 4. So $[0] = [4]$ and $[-1] = [3]$, but $[0] \ne [1]$. Note 4 does not divide $1-0 = 1$. There is nothing special about picking $n-1$ and $-1$. This may be helpful again in the case of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ we have $\cdots [-8] = [-4] = [0] = [4] = [8] = [12] = \cdots$. See the pattern? There is a similar pattern for $[1], [2]$ and $[3]$.

Comment: okay, but i don't see how we can come up with any patterns with [1], [2], and [3] since we cant get a number divisible by 4 with these? So, the n-1 term in the general formula is just there because it is necessary to have in order to have $k_1 - k_2$ divisible by n?

Comment: sorry , you are not referring to these 3 you listed then in reference to [1] [2] and [3] , if so than yes i get it.

Comment: The difference of the numbers must be divisible by 4 for them to represent the same class. So, $[-7] = [-3] = [1] = [5] = [8]$ and so on. We can shift a class by adding 4 (or any multiple of 4) and end up in the same class.

The $n-1$ is there because it is necessary to list a member of each class. The simplest way to get a member of each class in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is to list $0,1,2,\dots,n-1$.

Comment: So i basically understand it all thanks a lot , it helped me a ton. Accepttt ( sorry i must be getting annoying at this point) why not just have n ? Why the -1?

Comment: For any $n$ we have that $[n] = [0]$. So, if we went all the way up to $[n]$ we would want to omit $[0]$ and start at $[1]$. Look back at the middle example in the three examples of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ in the original answer.

Happy to help!

Comment: GOT IT! thanks so much.